# ToggleButton won't center in listview item

Tags: android, layout

I have a listview and the item is a LinearLayout with ToggleButton.
The ToggleButton is always on the top, I want it in the center at vertical.
Which tag in xml file I should use?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you paste the layout codes here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use android:gravity or android:layout_gravity as below example

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried both android:layout_gravity and android:gravity. Is there any other idea? Thank you. By the way the LinearLayout is horizontal.

Comment: I have to use android:layout_marginTop="5dip" to do this.